# How to add some accents in Microsoft Word Equation for geometry

Tags: geometry, education, math-software

I hope this will be the right place for my question. I'm working on a Geometry book and I have to type some accents and I cannot find the way to do it. Why Microsoft Word, because I tried with MathType and MathMagic but they make a huge mess on my files, even corrupted them. Also, I don't have time to learn Latex or money to pay another person to do it. I need these to be text, not images.

I'm desperate, and will be grateful of any hint.

The accents are the following:

- [Triangle notation over a letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Xyw.png)
- [Arc notation over letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHxAq.png)
- [Semiplane symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAfav.png)

Comment: I would say all the time you waste on this kind of problems can be used to learn $\LaTeX$. It is really a good investment.

Comment: Yes, probably. The thing this a now time job, at least for now. If I got another in the future, I will learn Latex for sure. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `\above`.

For $\overset{\Delta}{A}$, use `A \above("Delta Symbol")`, it'll become `A┴Delta` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for $\overset{\Delta}{A}$.

For $\overset{\cap}{AB}$, use `AB\above("cap symbol")`.

Comment: T H A N K   Y O U ! ! !

Comment: Please upvote if it was helpful, "thank you" comments aren't favored here at MSE. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot, do you have any idea about the semiplane symbol?

Comment: @alejorojas2k, The picture isn't clear for the symbol you're using for _semiplane_ and I always thought you use set builder notation to define planes or half planes.

Comment: Maybe use `A \above("__")`.

Comment: Oh yes, i mean half plane. The symbol to the left of the "="

Comment: In October 2020(ish) version of Word, I Was able to do this with <code>A \above(\Delta)</code> instead of <code>A \above("Delta Symbol")</code>

Answer (score -1):

Information was really helpful. To get complete list of all the shortcut for accents please see [Shortcut for putting accents in MS Word equation editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_h7ukThU_4&t=5s)